# Accurate method for computing the inverse of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

I am looking for an algorithm to compute the inverse of a matrix. I have tried some algorithms that by increasing the dimension of the matrix give a bad result. Mathematica's code works properly even for large matrices, now, I want to know which algorithm Mathematica uses for finding the inverse of a matrix or is there an accurate method for computing the inverse of a matrix. I will be grateful if someone helps me.

Comment: That depends on the matrix. Is it sparse, what is its condition number, is it close to being rank-deficient and what would the rank loss be? Black-box methods will do some classification along these lines and select an algorithm after that. // Are you sure you need the inverse or are you just interested in solving linear systems?

Comment: why do u need to compute the inverse? generally there are other ways to get around it since computing the inverse is very expensive